# JMS - Cannot retrieve message from queue. Happens intermittently

Tags: oracle11g, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

We have a Java class that listens to a database (Oracle) queue table and process it if there are records placed in that queue. It worked normally in UAT and development environments. Upon deployment in production, there are times when it cannot read a record from the queue. When a record is inserted, it cannot detect it and the records remain in the queue. This seldom happens but it happens. If I would give statistic, out of 30 records queued in a day, about 8 don't make it. We would need to restart the whole app for it to be able to read the records.

Here is a code snippet of my class..

```
public class SomeListener implements MessageListener{

public void onMessage(Message msg){
     InputStream input = null;
    try {
        TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) msg;
        String text = txtMsg.getText(); 
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.error("Parsing from the queue.... failed",e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //process text message
}

}
```

Weird thing we cant find any traces of exceptions from the logs.

Can anyone help? by the way we set the receiveTimeout to 10 secs

Comment: the code of the listener is not really what matters. The infrastructure code that reads from the queue should be more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> We would need to restart the whole app for it to be able to read the records.

The most common reason for this is the listener thread is "stuck" in user code (`//process text message`). You can take a thread dump with `jstack` or `jvisualvm` or similar to see what the thread is doing.

Another possibility (with low volume apps like this) is the network (most likely a router someplace in the network) silently closes an idle socket because it has not been used for some time. If the container (actually the broker's JMS client library) doesn't know the socket is dead, it will never receive any more messages.

The solution to the first is to fix the code; the solution to the second is to enable some kind of heartbeat or keepalives on the connection so that the network/router does not close the socket when it has no "real" traffic on it.

You would need to consult your broker's documentation about configuring heartbeats/keepalives.